# How to match timezone string +09:00?

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a string:

```
(GMT+09:00) Tokyo
```

I want to match `+09:00`.

I'm not very good at regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}
```

Comment: `[+-]\d\d:\d\d` is less to type. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work:

```
\+\d{2,}\:\d{2,}
```